# leaking poly irrigation

Tags: irrigation

I recently discovered the pavers in my back yard had a wet appearance.  After tracing the leak I found that one of the 700 black poly irrigation lines had a leak.  This is one of three lines I found buried at 6-8 inches below the pavers.

My concern is how the leak developed and if this is likely to happen in the future.  Is black poly not intended to be used like this?  Should I re-bury it in a conduit of PVC or something to protect it better?  It seems like once even a pinhole leak develops it would be very prone to attracting roots, yet this seems to be a very popular way to irrigate.

Comment: Are you referring to the 1/8" drip tubing type of black poly pipe, or the 1/2" - 5/8" stuff that is used to feed water to the small drip tubes? The larger stuff is fine to bury and it should be hard to put a hole in it under pavers and another 6" of soil, so most likely the hole was there from the start. If it's the little drip tube, I would have put it in something else like PVC just so it can be removed and replaced more easily. That stuff is more easily damaged.

Comment: @J.Raefield It's the larger, i think 700 stands for 0.7" OD.  The leak just showed up after years of no evidence of a leak, but it was small enough that I just cut out a small piece of line and put a two ended connector.  This is actually not the only place that has sprunk a leak, but the other was a lot closer to the surface.

Comment: @J.Raefield It happened again!  Now there is water bubbling from the soil next to the pavers a few feet from where the values are.